# How to use snackbar, splash screen and navigator at once?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get next page using navigator since when I try to press sign in button it doesn't take me to next page. **I am new in flutter**.

```
 class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
 const SignIn({super.key});

 @override
  State<SignIn> createState() => _SignInState();
 }

 class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  getanimatedscreen() {
   MySplashScreen().getSplashScreen(HomePage());
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
  getanimatedscreen();
    // TODO: implement initState
  super.initState();
  }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: SafeArea(
        top: true,
        bottom: true,
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/background18.jpg'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          //App Body Starts from here
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              //Using Gradient Text as Package in Pubsec
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                child: GradientText("Sign In Page!",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50.0),
                    gradientType: GradientType.linear,
                    colors: const [
                      Color.fromARGB(255, 211, 24, 11),
                      Color.fromARGB(255, 3, 47, 83),
                      Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                    ]),
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Center(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          //Field for Email
                          TextFormField(
                            maxLines: 1,
                            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 15.0,
                                color: Colors.blue[900],
                                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              enabled: true,
                              filled: true,
                              hintText: "Enter Email",
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              label: Text("Email"),
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 2.0),
                              hintTextDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                            ),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10.0,
                          ),
                          //Field for Password
                          TextFormField(
                            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            maxLines: 1,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 15.0,
                                color: Colors.blue[900],
                                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                            obscureText: true,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              filled: true,
                              hintText: "Enter Password",
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              label: Text(
                                "Password",
                              ),
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 2.0),
                              hintTextDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                            ),
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 20.0,
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 40.0,
                                width: 120.0,
                                child: ElevatedButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    final snackBar = SnackBar(
                                      content: Text(
                                          "You've been Successfully Signed In"),
                                      duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                                      action: SnackBarAction(
                                          label: "",
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            // Action to Undo or SnackBar Action
                                          }),
                                    );
                                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                        .showSnackBar(snackBar);
                                    getanimatedscreen();
                                  },
                                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                                    shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                          15), // <-- Radius
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Login',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 20.0,
                                        fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              OutlinedButton(
                                //SnackBar
                                onPressed: () {
                                  final snackBar = SnackBar(
                                    content: Text(
                                        "Please Enter Your Email in Next Page"),
                                    duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                                    action: SnackBarAction(
                                        label: "",
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          // Action to Undo or SnackBar Action
                                        }),
                                  );
                                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                      .showSnackBar(snackBar);
                                },
                                style: ButtonStyle(
                                    backgroundColor:
                                        MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                      Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                    shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                                        RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                    ))),
                                child: Text(
                                  "Forgot Password ?",
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 15.0,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 40.0,
                            width: 150.0,
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'firstRoute');
                                final snackBar = SnackBar(
                                  content:
                                      Text("Your Sign Up Page is Loading"),
                                  duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                                  action: SnackBarAction(
                                      label: "",
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        // Action to Undo or SnackBar Action
                                      }),
                                );
                                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                    .showSnackBar(snackBar);
                              },
                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                                shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.circular(15), // <-- Radius
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: Text(
                                'Sign-Up',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 20.0,
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
 }`*
```

`

`[Here you can see in image I am just getting an message only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EN4M.png)

Basically I am using Snackbar, Some Splash Screen Animations and Naviagtor function at a time. So when I try to fetch next page it only shows me the snackbar message.

Answer (score 0):

First you'll want to declutter your "onPressed" create a reusable snack bar. Paste this code in your state class just above initState

```
Future showSnack(String msg) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(msg)));
}
```

Now replace the code in the login button onPressed with this

```
onPressed: () {
showSnack("You've been Successfully Signed In").whenComplete((){Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'loginScreen')});
}
```

The assumption here is you have set up your routes in main.dart file

Comment: Thanks alot to you, It really means but it didn't add about splashscreen feature.

Comment: If 'firstscreen' is your splash screen then just replace 'loginScreen' with that